# Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu with buttons in ul li on the right (inline)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and I have this example:

As you can see I'm trying to add some buttons to the LI:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something here</a><button>A</button><button>B</button><button>C</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to have them inline on the right.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Flex layout for that: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Try this code ?

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li class="d-flex gap-2">
      <a class="dropdown-item me-auto p-2" href="#">Something here</a>
      <button class="p-2">A</button>
      <button class="p-2">B</button>
      <button class="p-2">C</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit : consider using flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<li class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something here</a>
  <div>
     <button>A</button>
     <button>B</button>
     <button>C</button>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: That doesn't work as the button appears a line under the li not inline